# BackboneJS Custom logic to parse response to model

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a custom logic to parse the REST response in my Backbone Model as below;

```
_parse: function(model) {

    var myCollection = new myCollection();
    var myModel = new myModel();

    if (model.myCollInside)
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < model.myCollInside.length; j++){
            myModel.set("attr1", new SomeModel1(model.myCollInside[j].attr1))
            myModel.set("attr2", new SomeModel2(model.myCollInside[j].attr2))
            myCollection.push(myModel);
        }
    }

    return {
        "myColl": myCollection
    };
}
```

Now the issue is even if I have 2 models and I do;

```
myCollection.push(myModel)
```

I just get one model finally in myCollection ?

Am I doing something wrong with using push for multiple items?

Comment: Is this method ON your model? You shouldn't be creating and adding to the collection from inside the `parse` method on a model.

Comment: @Mathletics - I agree.  Your question is also the first thing I asked myself when I read post.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are seeing only one model, but you need to place the creation of each new model INSIDE your loop.